stuck parsing a json object, to extract "key/value" pairs
I have an application that generates data in this form:
[
  {
    "metadata": {
      "labels": {
        "team": "eng"
      }
    },
    "spec": {
      "labels": {
        "instance_id": {
          "result": "x387j"
        },
        "another_field": {
          "result": "dfsf"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "metadata": {
      "labels": {
        "team": "sre"
      }
    },
    "spec": {
      "labels": {
        "instance_id": {
          "result": "sd9f"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

Labels, here are the keys in .metadata.labels and .spec.labels.
I can extract the labels as:
% jq -C ' .[] | ( .metadata.labels , .spec.labels ) | keys | .[] ' tmp/x.json | sort | uniq
"instance_id"
"team"

I want to extract the label and result pairs as:
"team": "eng"
"instance_id": "x387j"
"another_field": "dfsf"
"team": "sre"
"instance_id": "sd9f"

I can get the objects in .metadata.labels, albiet in different form:
% jq -C '.[] | (.metadata.labels) ' tmp/x.json
{
  "team": "eng"
}
{
  "team": "sre"
}

generates one part, but here, I am not able to remove just the braces.
The suggestion here, to remove brackets, quotes, and commas
removes the braces, but also the keys.
% jq -C '.[] | (.metadata.labels) | .[] ' tmp/x.json
"eng"
"sre"

Also, I am then not able to figure out to get the objects in .spec.labels.

Not sure if this is what you want, but .[] | .metadata.labels + (.spec.labels | .[] |= .result) would give you a stream of {"team":"eng","instance_id":"x387j"} {"team":"sre","instance_id":"sd9f"}.

@pmf. yes this works.   Now I need to understand it :-)

To exactly match your expecetd output format, append to_entries to destructure the objects, and @json to re-encode the strings, e.g.: … | to_entries[] | @json "\(.key): \(.value)" Demo

This generates the expected output :
jq -r '.[]
| .metadata.labels
  , (.spec.labels
  | with_entries(.value |= .result))
| to_entries[]
| map(tojson)
| join(": ")' tmp/x.json

